# How to properly catch errors using Promise?

Tags: reactjs, promise, request, fetch-api

I am studying react with an online course and I have a problem following along with the instructor. While using promise to deal with errors retrieving the data from the server, I have the following code to dispatch actions to my store:

```
export const fetchPromos = () => (dispatch) => {

dispatch(promosLoading());

return fetch(baseUrl + 'promotions')
.then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response;
    } else {
      var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
      error.response = response;
      throw error;
    }
  },
  error => {
        var errmess = new Error(error.message);
        throw errmess;
  })
.then(response => response.json())
.then(promos => dispatch(addPromos(promos)))
.catch(error => dispatch(promosFailed(error.message)));
}
```

After I shut down my json-server or purposely request a wrong resource from the server and reload my application, I get an UnHandled Rejection error in the browser instead of the one which I have defined. The instructor seems to see the error message correctly. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I am not able to understand how it relates to my code. Could you please point out where is the fault in this particular code as it appears to work for the instructor.

Comment: What's the error contained in the unhandled rejection? Is it the same error which you would expect to be coming from the failed `fetch`, or is it something else? It could be that your `promosFailed` function is throwing an error for some reason, or something of that nature. If the callback in that `.catch` throws an error for whatever reason, you will have an unhandled rejection.

Comment: Well i opened the console and had a look. The promosFailed function is being called properly with the error message "failed to fetch" (which is what should appear in place of the component). I have a simple if -else conditional rendering in the actual component. In this component, it is not recognizing that the error which it receives as props should be displayed and is instead trying to display the image leading to an undefined property error.

Comment: Ok, so basically, the issue is not in this code. As a side note, the `error =>` handler on the first `.then` seems to be completely redundant. You're just catching an error, making a new one with the same message as the original one, and throwing the new one. You can remove that handler entirely and have the same or better behavior.

Comment: @JLRishe Cheers figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

There is no error in this code, I found my problem as I had misspelled a prop causing it to be null in the rendering section and thereby bypassing my conditional rendering loop.

```
   if (isLoading) {
    return (
        <Loading />
    );
}
else if (errMess) {
    return (
        <h4>{errMess}</h4>
    );
}
```

Error prop was basically Null. (Causing errMess to be null)